# Edit lib.d.ts in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, typescript1.5

I want to edit lib.d.ts to change the ImageData.data from number[] to UInt8Array (the correct Uint8ClampedArray type isn't available). I did this in Visual Studio 2013 by just editing the lib.d.ts file in the CommonExtensions/Typescript directory.

I've done the same in Visual Studio 2015 and intellisense shows my change, and when I right click and go to the definition, it goes to my version of lib.d.ts.

However when I compile, I get errors that the ImageDate.data member is a number[].

Where is the compiler getting this definition from and is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this. Apparently the lib.d.ts used by the tsc compiler is in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.5\ but that's not the one used by intellisense. Fixing the lib.d.ts file there works.